# Update statement error in SQL procedure

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am writing a stored procedure to update data in a table where I will pass a string with the new data `(col1='new values', col2='new 2 values')`. But when I am compiling my stored procedure , i am getting an error :- "missing equal sign".

Even i tried doing it in a different way (commented code in proc) but that is also giving an error.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE "MY_UPDATE_PROC"(update_values IN VCHAR2,myid IN INT)

sqlStmt VARCHAR2(1024);

BEGIN

UPDATE MY_TEST_TABLE SET update_values WHERE (TEST_Id = myid);

--sqlStmt := 'UPDATE MY_TEST_TABLE SET ' ||  update_values || ' WHERE TEST_Id = ' ||myid ;

-- EXECUTE sqlStmt;

END;
```

Comment: `CHARVAR2`? What is it?

Answer (score 0):

Try this (untested):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE "MY_UPDATE_PROC"(update_values IN VARCHAR2, myid IN NUMBER) AS
  sqlStmt VARCHAR2(1024);
BEGIN
  sqlStmt := 'UPDATE MY_TEST_TABLE SET ' ||  update_values || ' WHERE TEST_Id = ' || myid;
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE sqlStmt;
END;
/
```

The datatype of your first parameter should be VARCHAR2 (maybe just a typo in your post)

Answer (score 0):

Syntax of simple update statement in Oracle is:

```
Update <table_name>
   set <column_name> = some_value
 where <conditions..>
```

You update statement is missing `= some_value` part that you need to provide.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE "MY_UPDATE_PROC"(P_update_values IN CHARVAR2, p_myid IN INT)

BEGIN

  UPDATE MY_TEST_TABLE 
     SET col1 = p_update_values 
   WHERE TEST_Id = p_myid;

END;
/
```

Using Dynamic SQL, although not required in this case:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE "MY_UPDATE_PROC"(p_update_values IN VARCHAR2, p_myid IN NUMBER) AS
  sqlStmt VARCHAR2(1024);
BEGIN
  sqlStmt := 'UPDATE MY_TEST_TABLE SET col1 = :a WHERE TEST_Id = :b';
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE sqlStmt USING p_update_values, p_myid;
END;
/
```

Things to be noted:

1) Always use meaningful and different names that are other than column names for the parameters.

2) Always use bind variables, :a and :b in above examples, to avoid SQL Injections and improve overall performance if you are going to call this procedure multiple times.

Comment: my update_values will contain col1='Some Value', col2='Some Value' . With this I will not bother about the number of fields. Caller must take care of it.

Comment: when I used the suggested SQL( keyword using) then getting error:
Encountered  the symbol "=" when expecting one of the following :=,.,@ ...

Comment: @CrazyC: That's because your parameter "update_values" isn't a single value, it's a complete SET clause. Assigning it to a bind variable won't work in this case.

Comment: That is something I would not suggest, but if still you want to use like this, then in the input string, use two single quotes not one.  Eg. use `col1=''new values'', col2=''new 2 values''`.